# Elasticsearch filter results with AND query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to work out how to do a query on a list/array and then do an AND query to further narrow down my results. The part I'm not sure how to do is that I need the AND query to only be applied to items matching the items in the list from first query and not all items.

My data looks something like this:

```
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "person": {
        "name": "Jimmy",
        "addresses": [
          {
            "spend": 1000,
            "state": "CA"
          },
          {
            "spend": 5000,
            "state": "CA"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "name": "Mary",
        "addresses": [
          {
            "spend": 10000,
            "state": "TX"
          },
          {
            "spend": 500,
            "state": "CA"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to find all persons where persons.person.addresses.state == "CA" AND persons.person.addresses.spend > 2000

If I do this query:

```
"query": {
   "query_string": {
      "query": "(persons.person.addresses.state:CA) AND (persons.person.addresses.spend > 2000)"
   }
}
```

I get back both Jimmy and Mary because Mary has an address where state is "CA" even though spend for CA is not > 2000. What I really want to get back is only Jimmy since he only has an address object where both the state value is "CA" and that same object has spend > 2000.

I hope that's clear. I really appreciate any pointers on how to resolve this.

Thanks

G

Comment: bool or filter query might be useful in such cases

Comment: There is a typo/bug in your query. Instead of state > 2000, it should be spend > 2000.

Comment: If you have a hit on one of the `person` objects it is going to return the `persons` object, can you be index the `person` objects individually, i.e. not with in a `persons` array object? Also, you should indexing `nested` types because of the arrays, and using nested queries and filters.

Comment: Thanks @DanTuffery - you are correct, it seems I need to change my schema to a nested type so it can queried correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DanTuffery it seems I have to change my schema to a nested type.

http://joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-nested-mapping-and-filter/